# MySQL InnoDB deadlock between select for update and insert

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

### Background :

In **MySQL 5.7.18**
I have a table named 'test' defined as below:

```
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_name_x01` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

It has only 1 row :

```
id | name
2  | eva
```

Now I start 2 transctions, both in **REPEATABLE-READ** isolation level, and do the commands as below:

1. T1 : begin;
2. T2 : begin;
3. T2 : select * from test where name='eva' for update;
4. T1 : select * from test where name='eva' for update; (now T1 holds)
5. T2 : insert into test values (1, 'eva'); (**dead lock**, T1 is rolled back)

### InnoDB log:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2017-05-06 20:24:28 0x126df8000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 112142, ACTIVE 15 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 139, OS thread handle 4950491136, query id 997169 localhost root Sending data
select * from test where name='eva' for update
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 72 index test_name_x01 of table `promotion`.`test` trx id 112142 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 657661; asc eva;;
 1: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 112141, ACTIVE 19 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 138, OS thread handle 4947148800, query id 997170 localhost root update
insert into test values (1, 'eva')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 72 index test_name_x01 of table `promotion`.`test` trx id 112141 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 657661; asc eva;;
 1: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 5 n bits 72 index test_name_x01 of table `promotion`.`test` trx id 112141 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 3; hex 657661; asc eva;;
 1: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

### My thoughts

Based on my research, below is what I think might be the cause of deadlock. But need professional confirmation.

```
1. T1 : begin;
2. T2 : begin;
3. T2 : select * from test where name='eva' for update;
```

step 3 requires: IX lock, next-key lock on index 'name' (negative infinity, 'eva']

```
4. T1 : select * from test where name='eva' for update;
```

step 4 requires: IX lock, next-key lock on index 'name' (negative infinity, 'eva'] 
IX lock is compatible to IX, so T1 can acquire it without T2's release.
**next-key lock contains actually 2 parts: record X + gap, since conflicting locks can be held on a gap by different transactions, T1 also holds gap lock without waiting for T2.** So T1 is only waiting for T2 to release the record lock(on secondary index name='eva' and clustered index id='1') to proceed.

```
5. T2 : insert into test values (1, 'eva'); (dead lock, T1 is rolled back)
```

step 5 : Here the **insert requires insert intension lock, which is not compatible with gap lock.** So T2 is waitting for T1 to release its gap lock. But meanwhile T1 is waitting for T2 to release record X lock.

========================================================================

### Updates, found out more interesting facts that my explanation above cannot explain.

Moreover for step 5, after trying with different ID values, I have below observation :

If the table is preloaded with multiple rows with different IDs and with same name 'eva', **deadlock is ONLY reproducible if the ID value try to insert in step 5 is less than the minimum ID of all existing rows.**

For example preload table with

```
id | name
2  | eva
4  | eva
```

for step 5 above,

```
insert (0, 'eva') => deadlock 
insert (1, 'eva') => deadlock
insert (3, 'eva') => NO deadlock
insert (5, 'eva') => NO deadlock
```

Comment: The gap before the 2 from the primary key would no longer exist if are allowed to you insert 0 or 1.  If you insert 0, it becomes 2 gaps, one before 0 and one before 2... if you insert 1 it becomes a different gap, from infimum to before 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* store numbers into `VARCHARs` without quotes.  That defeats any attempt at using the index.

**More**

In general, ...

When a single row can be identified via an index, only that row will be "locked".  Single-row locking *usually* avoids deadlocks by "delaying" one transaction until another releases its lock.

When the entire table must be scanned, *all* rows *may* need to be locked.  This *may* not allow for "delaying", and go into deadlock.

In any case, ...

Plan for deadlocks by being ready to replay the entire transaction.  *Some* deadlocks are unavoidable.

(Sorry for being vague; there are too many possible variations here.  Fix the quotes or index; that *should* avoid *most* deadlocks.)

Comment: I don't think so. MySQL will do the conversion.

Comment: MySQL does do the conversion, but it does it backwards -- varchar to number.  So each `id` gets converted to a number when looking up so that it can be compared to the unquoted number in the query.  Hence, you won't get the benefit of any index on `id`.

Comment: Ok. But does this have something to do with the deadlock issue I'm facing?

Comment: Issue is exactly the same after quoting the `id` in `insert` statement.

Comment: @superluli - see my addition.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your reply, I understand there are many causes for a deadlock and I do have retry on failed transactions because of deadlock. But for the case I mentioned above particularly, I just want to know the cause :)